# How do I register a custom converter so that @GeoShapeField picks it up?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, geojson, spring-data-elasticsearch, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch (5) to automagically write third-party data into an ES (8) index. The data contains geodata in GML format, which is parsed into a nested `Map<String, Object>`.

In my POJO I have a field

```
@GeoShapeField
private Map<String, Object> geometry;
```

This is written perfectly fine in many cases; however, the data I get can also contain e.g. `Envelope`, which is not supported by GeoJson but could be imported without problems into ES.

I can write simple custom `ReadingConverter`/`WritingConverter`s - but how can I register them in a way that `@GeoShapeField` automatically chooses them when appropriate?

I see that `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.GeoConverters` is responsible for choosing the correct converter, esp. `.GeoJsonToMapConverter` and `.MapToGeoJsonConverter`. How would I correctly extend the class/replace it, so that @GeoShapeField looks for an additional (or more) type(s)?

Comment: `@GeoShapeField` is only used for building the index mapping of a property, it has nothing to do with the conversion of the actual entity that is written to or read fro Elasticsearch. You'd need a custom converter to convert some custom class to `<Map<String, Object>` that will be written to Elasticsearch and back from such a map to a custom class. But you already seem to have a map so there is no converter needed. Can you clarify your problem and provide a minimal runnable example that shows the problem?

Comment: Thanks, seems I had quite some misconceptions. My real problem seems to be converting from the GML 3 structure to a GeoJson mapping, or at least to one ES can understand (e.g. in the case of Envelope) - however, I feel this is out of scope for spring-data-elasticsearch, and thus this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by P.J.Meisch in the comments, I had several understanding problems, which led to the formulation of the question.

The answer to my actual question is straightforward: for Envelope, Elasticsearch expects

```
"myField": {
    "type" : "envelope",
    "coordinates" : [ [100.0, 1.0], [101.0, 0.0] ]
}
```

To achieve this using spring-data-elasticsearch, it is enough to provide a simple translation into a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> myField = new HashMap<>();
myField.put("type", "envelope");
myField.put("coordinates", Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(100.0, 1.0), Arrays.asList(101.0, 0.0)));
```

The point over which I tripped was the **data**. I receive bounding boxes specifying lower left and upper right corners. However, ES expects upper left and lower right corners for a bounding box. After switching the respective positions, everything works now.